# C# Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

Where can I find references and full documentation for the C# speech recognition namespace. MSDN only provides a very brief description of the members and nothing more from what I can find. Is there an absolute resource for theses kinds of things. Mostly everything I'm learning is from other tutorials or snippets in forums.

Comment: Here's the most [absolute resource](http://www.wikipedia.org) in existence.

Comment: [Getting started with speech recognition programming questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853037/getting-started-with-speech-recognition-programming-questions)

Comment: @mehrdad seriously why bother commenting if its just so unrelated.
@AB Kolan that is not full documentation, please read the question thoroughly.

Comment: This example seems to cover all the necessary aspects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394922.aspx#Y564

Comment: @Mitch Thank you, dont see why I couldn't get those results in msdn. All I got was the definitions.

Comment: @Anon: added as answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Intro: [Speech Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394880.aspx)

Code examples covering most of the basics:

[Getting Started with Speech Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394922.aspx#Y564)

> The basic operations that speech
>   recognition applications perform:
>   - Starting the speech recognizer.
>
> - Creating a recognition grammar.
> - Loading the grammar into a speech recognizer.
> - Registering for speech recognition event notification.
> - Creating a handler for the speech recognition event.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the latest MSDN pages on System.Speech.Recognition for .NET 4 are skimpy on the details, but the older pages for .NET 3.5 have more details. For a quick comparison I just grabbed these two pages:

- RecognitionResult Class - .NET 3.5 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognitionresult(v=VS.90).aspx

vs.

- RecognitionResult Class - .NET 4.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognitionresult(v=VS.100).aspx

The .NET 3.5 docs have detailed remarks and examples. The .NET 4.0 versions just have definitions.

I found the helpfile that comes with the Server Speech Platform SDK has details that the .NET 4.0 MSDN pages leave off - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b1604d3-4f66-4241-9a21-90a294a5c9a4.

To get started with .NET speech, there is a very good article that was published a few years ago at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx. It is probably the best introductory article I’ve found so far. It is a little out of date, but very helfpul. (The AppendResultKeyValue method was dropped after the beta and likely other breaking changes.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you add the library for Speech Recognition.

```
using System.Speech.Recognition
```

If you cannot load the library, you can add it by using add reference.
Go

> Project>Add Reference>Browse

Generally, **System.Speech.dll** is in C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0

Here, the example code that recognizes "Yes","No","In","Out" is below:

```
namespace SpeechRecognition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();
            Choices ch = new Choices();
            ch.Add(new string[] { "yes", "no","in","out" });

            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(ch);

            Grammar gr = new Grammar(gb);

            sr.LoadGrammar(gr);

            sr.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechRecognition);

        }

        private void sr_SpeechRecognition(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);

        }
    }
}
```